# Running a remote process on local

Tags: ssh, remote

Is there an existing tool that does something like:

1. Download an existing program from a remote server to local machine when the remote machine signals.
2. Execute it automatically.

Otherwise is it possible to do it with `ssh`?

Please notice that running a command on `ssh` starts the program on the remote machine rather than local.

Comment: What is the purpose of the downloading and running of code? A job queue system? Something else?

Comment: The program is being developed on machine A. It must run on every new version automatically on machine B. I need to avoid the manual updating and re-running and I'm not planning to develop an auto-updater right now.

Comment: Sounds something like CI - https://github.com/kahun/awesome-sysadmin#continuous-integration--continuous-deployment

Comment: Yea that was what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: How should the remote machine signal that the copy is ready to be downloaded? Or can we use the remote machine to push a copy to the local machine for execution?

Answer (score 1):

A simple shell script could do this.

I hope I understood correctly.

machineA.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
# send file from machine A to machine B
scp /path/on/machineA/binary user@MachineB:/path/on/machineB/binary

# ssh into machine B and launch machineB.sh
ssh user@MachineB /path/to/machineB.sh
```

machineB.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# execute file on machine B
chmod +x /path/on/machineB/binary
/path/on/machineB/binary
```

Run script from machine A each time you need to test new program. Can be done as a final part of a build script.